Setting a `sed` command as `GIT_EDITOR` doesn't work correctly in `git rebase --interactive`
I have the following Git repository (git log --oneline):
658f9f0 (HEAD -> master) baz
4da6df7 bar
4f95d1b foo

When I run the command:
GIT_EDITOR='sed -iEn "2 p" --' git rebase --interactive -- HEAD~2,
I would expect only commits "foo" and "baz" to remain in the branch but instead I get:
1e437ac (HEAD -> master) baz
658f9f0 baz
4da6df7 bar
4f95d1b foo

I've checked whether the sed command works correctly (by removing the option -i) and it seems to return the correct todo list:
pick 658f9f0 baz # empty

If I remove the custom GIT_EDITOR and edit the file manually, by removing every line but the 2nd one (so create the same todo list as above), it works as expected.
Why it is different when I use sed -i?

I've also checked what happens if the sed command replaces pick with drop in other lines instead of removing them.
(GIT_EDITOR='sed -iE "2! s/^pick/drop/" --' git rebase --interactive -- HEAD~2)
This works fine but I don't know if I can rely on it or if it works by a fluke.

@CharlesDuffy Counterpoint #1: GIT_EDITOR='sed -En "2 p" --' git rebase --interactive -- HEAD~2 (so the same command without -i) prints the correct todo list to terminal, as I wrote, which proves that it was parsed correctly.
Counterpoint 2#: Git explicitly shows an example with quotes in the manual page for variables.

Which platform? Are you on an OS where -i has a mandatory following argument? (On BSDs like MacOS, f/e, you'd need it to be sed -i "" -En "2 p" --; with your existing code the En would be treated not as additional options, but as a filename extension to use when creating a backup of the original/pre-edit content).

@CharlesDuffy That was it, thank you! -i -En works correctly. Should I close this as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"?

Or I can close it as a duplicate of an existing question caused by that sed usage issue -- it's a fairly common gotcha.

Btw, this is not exclusively a Mac problem. I'm on the latest Linux Mint right now.

nod. It's just a bit different on MacOS, since there you need the separate "" argument, but on Linux (or other platforms using GNU sed) you can leave that out.
